# Switching Scenes in JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, stage

I am switching two scenes in my Javafx program. But i am getting following errors when i press the specific button:-

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\ZeusPortal\Java\Lesson6\out\production\Lesson6;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Intro5
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: cycle detected: parent = VBox@6e07849a, node = VBox@6e07849a
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:445)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
    at popup.showing(popup.java:25)
    at Intro5.lambda$start$0(Intro5.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using two stages with two different scenes in two different classes. And i am switching among these two scene on a button click, present in my main class.

***Mainclass***

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class MainClass extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
    public void start(Stage Mystage) throws Exception{
        Mystage.setTitle("Primary Stages!");
        Label lbl = new Label("This is Scene of a primary Stage.");
        Button btn = new Button("Click me!");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> popup.showing("Pop-up Window","This Pop-Up window is extremely awesome."));
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);
        Scene sn = new Scene(layout,400,400);
        Mystage.setScene(sn);
        Mystage.show();
    }
}
```

***Second Scene Class***

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
public class popup {
    public static void showing(String title, String Message){
        Stage stg = new Stage();
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.setTitle(title);
        stg.setMinWidth(300);
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.setText(Message);
        Button btn = new Button("Close!");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> stg.close());
        VBox layout = new VBox();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(layout,btn);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene sn = new Scene(layout,500,500);
        stg.setScene(sn);
        stg.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

This is my whole scenario. When i am supposed to click on a button in my main class, a pop up stage should appear displaying some message. This pop up stage is programmed in me pop up class. But whenever i click on the button in my main class, above mentioned exception(Actually bunch of errors) appears, terminating my application. Kindly help me if possible. JavaFX is really complicated library, and i have just started working in it. I am not used to with this Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the `VBox` inside itself. Change this line:

```
 layout.getChildren().addAll(layout,btn);
```

to

```
 layout.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);
```

(In popup).

Comment: One of the most important reason i give to myself when i dislike programming. So simple mistake i was making.